# how to show that a series converges without use of limits.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Just wanted to know if there is another method?

Of the methods I know:

1. Ratio test
2. Comparison test
3. Root test
4. Integral test
5. Limit comparison test

All make use of limits.

The reason why I am asking question, is because my class mate told the teacher that limits is not on the syllabus thus he should spend time talking about it, and focus on the test. (a level)

Comment: I'd say series convergence inherently involves limits...

Comment: When we say that a sequence converges, we mean that it converges to a limit, so it is rather difficult to discuss convergence in any generality without. If you are working over $\mathbb R$ and have a sequence is increasing and you can show that it is bounded above, then you know it has a limit (similarly decreasing and bounded below).

Comment: There is a criterion that says that if you have a decreasing sequence of *positive* $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ reals, then the series $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty (-1)^n a_n$ converges, provided that $\lim a_n = 0$ (which is usually straightforward to check). Is that the type of result you mean?

Comment: Wikipedia is your friend, as always: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_%28mathematics%29#Convergence_tests

Comment: @MaoYiyi Well if you are working in a complete metric space and can show your series is cauchy then you know it converges to something.

Comment: @Feanor I was asking because the other student said that limits where not the syllabus, thus we didn't need to know them, but I was trying to think how are we going to learn sequences without learning limits.